# ngx-bootstrap/dropdown not working with angular4 and bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

Befor installing ngx-bootstrap 1.9.3 everything is fine. My project works perfect. After installing ngx-bootstrap project stopped.
If I remove ngx-bootstrap my project runs perfect.

I'm using systemjs.config.js like that:

```js
map: {
    app: 'src/app',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    'jquery': 'npm:jquery/',
    'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
    'moment': 'npm:moment',
    'symbol-observable': 'npm:symbol-observable'
  },
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
      main: './index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'moment': {
      main: 'moment.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'symbol-observable': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
```

Usage like Valor-software page:

```js
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

in app.module.ts :

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

in systemjs.config.js add

```
'ngx-bootstrap':            'npm:ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',

in  map: {} section
```

Comment: How can I find the location for systemjs.config.js ?

Comment: It is normally at the root of the project. In the same folder where the index.html is and "app" folder it